# Cross-browser css issue where height:100% doesn't get inherited by child elements in a table

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I've inherited a web application from about 2005 that has lots of table-styling in it, see https://jsfiddle.net/6t7r1fma

```
<table style="height:50px">
  <tr style="height:100%">
    <td style="height:100%">
      <div style="overflow-y:scroll;height:100%">
        <table style="table-layout:fixed">
          <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Five</td>
            <td>Six</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Seven</td>
            <td>Eight</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Nine</td>
            <td>Ten</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Eleven</td>
            <td>Twelve</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The issue is that I want the inner table to be as large as I want, but contained in the overflow div which can be scrolled vertically.  It works in Chrome but not in Firefox (less important) and IE (more important).  What's happening is that the overflow div is taking the height of the child table instead of the parent table, and the result is that the inner table is displayed in its entirety.

Any thoughts?  Rewriting the HTML is not really an option, so hopefully there's a CSS solution.

Comment: Currently Firefox has a market share of `6.73%`, while IE stands at `4.37%`. Why would you consider not working in IE more important than not working in another browser with a larger market share? I'm not a fanboy of any, but I was wondering on reasoning. Regarding your question, please note you would drastically increase the chances of getting a proper answer by providing a [mcve] rather than describing the issue.

Comment: Well, ideally I could get this working on every browser but I've basically given up on Firefox because of other issues I've encountered along the way.  I still have hopes of getting this working on IE.  My main concern is that I'm doing something really wrong if the browsers are divided on how to interpret it.

Comment: How would I go about making this more minimal, complete or verifiable?  I thought providing the exact code that caused the issue, and then in addition describing that issue was pretty good.

Comment: You could place your code in an inspectable snippet (use the `<>` button). Ideally, you should also place the styles in the `CSS` section of the snippet, so people could modify it with more ease. Fact is anyone trying to help will need to create a snippet of it. If you create it yourself you're showing some consideration for their time and effort. But, in principle, you are right, your code is actually verifiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the way tables work can be summed up by: ***they size themselves around content***.  The only solution you have is to pass the `max-height` from the outer table onto the `<div>` inside its cell.

If you'd rather do that dynamically, without changing your markup (which would be the right way to go), you could:

- hide the contents of your table entirely, using CSS and let the cell get *normal* size
- on page load (after the table was added to `DOM` and rendered), get the height of the parent `<table>` and place it as `max-height` on the `<div>` contained in your `<td>`. Of course, this can only be done in `javascript`.

Besides the above, the only other option you have is placing the `max-height` on the `div` inside the `td` directly (which is what the solutions below do using `javascript`).

Note I added an `id` on general principles, to contain it, but as long as you know what you're doing, and this doesn't affect anything else, you don't really need it. Proof of concept:

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('#fix>tbody>tr>td>div');
[].forEach.call(divs, function(div){
   div.style.maxHeight = div.parentNode.clientHeight + 'px';
   div.style.display = 'block';
})
```

```css
#fix>tbody>tr>td>div {display: none;}
```

```html
<table style="height:50px" id="fix" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr style="height:100%">
    <td style="height:100%">
      <div style="overflow-y:scroll;height:100%">
        <table style="table-layout:fixed">
          <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Five</td>
            <td>Six</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Seven</td>
            <td>Eight</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Nine</td>
            <td>Ten</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Eleven</td>
            <td>Twelve</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

If you're already loading `jQuery` in the project, you should probably use this instead (haven't tested, but it should include IE8, which the above doesn't):

```js
$('#fix>tbody>tr>td>div').each(function(){
   $(this).css({
     "max-height":$(this).parent().height() + 'px',
      display:"block"
   });
})
```

```css
#fix>tbody>tr>td>div {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table style="height:50px" id="fix" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr style="height:100%">
    <td style="height:100%">
      <div style="overflow-y:scroll;height:100%">
        <table style="table-layout:fixed">
          <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Five</td>
            <td>Six</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Seven</td>
            <td>Eight</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Nine</td>
            <td>Ten</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Eleven</td>
            <td>Twelve</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

Note that due to user agent default styles, table elements might be rendered in different browsers with small spacing (cellpadding and cellspacing) (usually 1-2px) and those will be deducted from the available height. You could prevent this behavior by setting both `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` to 0 on the parent `<table>` (like I did) or by resetting user agent default styles for `<table>` elements.

Comment: I agree that JavaScript is the way to go here.  You also identified the root cause of the issue that tables are sized around the content (albeit differently for different browsers, apparently).  My solution ended up being just like you said; the inner table's display set to none, and then on load I set the max-height to the calculated height before resetting the display to block.

Answer (score 1):

Can you add a display block to the parent table and it's table body, table rows and table cells? This works in Firefox and IE 11 (not sure how far back you have to go.)

https://jsfiddle.net/fwuzqo3o/

```
<table style="height:50px; display: block;">
  <tbody style="height: 100%; display: block;">
    <tr style="height:100%; display: block;">
      <td style="height:100%; display: block;">
        <div style="overflow-y:scroll;height:100%">
          <table style="table-layout:fixed">
            <tr>
              <td>One</td>
              <td>Two</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
              <td>Three</td>
              <td>Four</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Five</td>
              <td>Six</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Seven</td>
              <td>Eight</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Nine</td>
              <td>Ten</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Eleven</td>
              <td>Twelve</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I think this is a really good answer and exactly solves the problem as I laid it out.  The only reason I didn't accept it is because I got two great answers, and the other one is a bit more scaleable for a larger project.  This is certainly the more useful of the two if JavaScript is not a consideration.